# AsyncTask is freezing my UI and I am not using .get()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to using AsyncTask.  It is freezing my program and I am not sure why.  I am looking for a way to return the results from db that I put in an arrayList.  I used break point and my doInBackground(String... args) is grabbing the information I want from my local db.  After that my program freezes up.  I am not sure why.  I have looked up solutions on stack and google and found that a lot of people are using .get() and they shouldn't.  Unless there is something I am missing I am not.  Here is my code, any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    task = new LoadAllProducts();
    task.execute("");

}

class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {




    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jParser.makeHttpRequest (url_all_product, "GET",
                    params);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VISITORS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String company = c.getString(TAG_COMPANY);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_COMPANY, company);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's freezing and not just taking too long to process? Those are different things. I'd suggest putting `Log.d()` lines after each line of your `onCreate()` method and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: My program is still not doing anything and it has been ten minutes

Comment: Maybe your `AsyncTask` is not returning the answer you expect, but that doesn't mean your `AsyncTask` is blocking an execution (10 minutes is a huge time to hang, it would have hanged before). I still recommend the `Log.d()` technique and see what happens.

Comment: I used break point to see what is going on and when I exit AsynTask the program doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Your AsyncTask modifies `productsList` from a background thread -- since you have used an ArrayList this is not thread-safe. Either use a thread-safe collection (see `Collections.synchronizedList()`) or modify the list only from `onPostExecute()`

Comment: "My program is still not doing anything and it has been ten minutes" -- what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I want a way to return the values I put in produceList

Comment: "I want a way to return the values I put in produceList" -- you don't "return" them. You *use* them in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AsyncTask` is not freezing your UI. Your application simply does not do anything with the UI! Your `onCreate` method does not use `setContentView` to set the contents of your activity, so it will be left blank and that's probably what's leading you to believing that the application is hung.

Your `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` returns null, which means it returns no results to the `onPostExecute` method. You should return the result of your http request in your `doInBackground` and then in `onPostExecute` make use of the data to display it in your UI. The `onPostExecute` method will be executed on the foreground (UI) thread.

Whatever you return in your `doInBackground` method will be passed as the parameter of your `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Thanks I added finish() after the call to AsyncTask.  Now I gotta figure out how to get the results from the onPostExecute.

Comment: Don't call finish(). That would effectively terminate your Activity. Set the content of your Activity to some control in onCreate and then update the contents of that control in your onPostExecute method.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why this is happening for you, I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary. However, I recommend that you use some different libraries to help you clean up your code. I recommend [http-request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) for communicating with your endpoint and then using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to turn your JSON objects into POJO's. You can also use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) if GSON ends up being too slow (ex: downloading 10's of thousands of lines of JSON).

Comment: Is there a workaround you can recommend?  I know that when it gets down to return null I have the info I need.

Answer (score 1):

Once you exit the `AsyncTask` execution, the program doesn't have to go "nowhere", it just stays idle because your `.execute()` method is the last of your `onCreate()` method.

You could have listeners to fire certain events, but seems that you have just the feeling it's frozen because your `AsyncTask` is probably not returning/doing what you expect to do and you think it has been hung, but 10 minutes is a huge amount of time to wait to determine something is irresponsive (it would hang much earlier), so my tip is that probably it's your `AsyncTask` execution who's not processing what you're doing, and you should put several breakpoints or `Log.d()` lines to debug it and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I used breakpoints and went through the code several times.  It gets what I want from my db and then does nothing else.  I want to return productsList(an ArrayList), but doInBackground needs to be a string.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html reference, concretly the `AsyncTask's generic types` part which explains how to pass/return several types of variables.